# Matrix and Tensor Multiplication

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix X of dimensions nx2.

Using this matrix I want to construct a tensor Y of dimensions 2x2xn.
So that Y(:, :, i) = X(i, :)'*X(i, :)

Can this be done in Matlab without a loop using some linear algebra operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bsxfun` based solution -

```
Y = permute(bsxfun(@times, X, permute(X,[1 3 2])),[3 2 1])
```

Comment: +1 If the OP really wanted `'` a complex conjugate would be needed here. But he probably meant just `.'`

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah if not mentioned in the question, it's safer from answerer's point of view to assume `'` as transpose I would think.